# select2 with MVC razor change only triggered once

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, jquery-events

This is my Razor view.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.wellModel.APINumber, new { id = "apiselect2" })
```

This is my script to get the selected value from select2:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#apiselect2").on("select2-selecting", function () {
                alert($("#apiselect2").select2('data').text);
           });
});
```

For some reason it only shows it to me once and if I change from let's say selected value 777 to 321 no alert is displayed.

I also tried to change this to:

```
$("#apiselect2").on("change", function () { ...
```

Still nothing. Really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have identical `id`s for every item, so the change event won't be fired if you select item with the same `id`, because `id` of newly selected item is identical.

To resolve the problem, add different `id`s to items.